# Why are tick labels all at origin on TikZ axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why are all the labels drawn at the origin instead of their specified positions?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
    \draw[->, thin] (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
    \foreach \i in {1/9,2/8,1/3,2/3,7/9,8/9} {
        \draw (\i,-.01)--(\i,.01);
            \node[below] (\i,0) {$\small{\i}$};
    }         
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In `\node[below] (\i,0) {$\small{\i}$};`, the `(\i,0)` is treated as specifying node name, not position. Thus the default position `(0,0)` is used. Try `\node[below] at (\i,0) {$\small{\i}$};` instead. You might want to adjust the font size for node text then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up [my own comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648002/why-are-tick-labels-all-at-origin-on-tikz-axis#comment1615025_648002):

- The key is the missing `at` in `\node[...] <missing at> (\i,0) {...};`.
- Also I find options `anchor=west, rotate=-75, font=\tiny` give nicer output.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
    \draw[->, thin] 
        (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
    \foreach \i in {1/9,2/8,1/3,2/3,7/9,8/9} {
        \draw (\i,-.01)--(\i,.01);
            \node[anchor=west, rotate=-75, font=\tiny] at (\i,0) {$\small{\i}$};
    }         
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]