# Use exact fractions at tick marks with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this MWE, I want to be able to use rational fractions $\frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{2}{9}$ as labels at tick marks on an x-axis. How can the following be modified to do that?

(In the real application, there would be a longer list of tick marks and their labels, hence my wanting to "automate" this.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
    \draw[->, thin] 
        (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
    \foreach \i in {1/9,2/9,1/3,2/3,7/9,8/9} {
        \draw (\i,-.01)--(\i,.01);
    };
    \foreach \x/\y in {{1,9},{2,9}}{
        \node[anchor=north] at (\the\numexpr \x /\y,0) {$\tfrac{\x}{\y}$};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Two issues are involved:

1. Getting the syntax right for "special handling of pairs" (page 1002 in prfmanual.pdf; and
2. For a given pair — the numerator and denominator of the exact rational fraction to be printed as the tick label, how to form the numerical expression from them that gives the horizontal coordinate for the node.

Note that I *cannot* simply use something like

```
\foreach \xy in {1/9,2/9}{
    \node[anchor=north] at (\xy,0) {$\xy$}
};
```

because that does not format the fraction using `\tfrac`.

Further note: If at all possible, I would like to be able to use the TikZ/pgf `\foreach` construct to iterate over a list of pairs; and I would strongly prefer *not* to use any exp3 constructs, since I find the exp3 syntax even more impenetrable than TikZ syntax!

*Related:* [Why are tick labels all at origin on TikZ axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648002/13492)

Comment: Look at the linked answer carefully on how the coordinate is specified, and do the same way. Just "modify" it similar to the answer you link to

Comment: @user202729: that answer does *not* do what I want: I want to be able to print each tick label at a coordinate x/y in the form $\tfrac{x}{y}$. (I edited question just now to clarify that I need to use LaTeX math epression.) The linked answer prints it as an exact rational fraction, but in the form x/y rather than in the LaTeX/math-formatted way I want.

Comment: Ok let me spell it out... See in the linked answer the coordinate is `(\i,-.01)`, and `\i` is `1/9`. So you need something expands to `(1/9,-.01)` (or `(1/9,0)`).

Comment: @user202729: No! Please look again at my expanded, clarified post. I need to use a pair of integers, one for a numerator ant the other for a denominator. I need to use that pair first to calculate their quotient  giving the x-coordinate of the node; and then to feed into a LaTex math tfrac expression with of course 2 arguments, namely, the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Okay looks like where you're really'll stuck at is part 1. Part 2 should not be hard (also you should be able to see why numexpr usage there is wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't quite understand the expansion order of `\foreach` , just use `\clist_map_inline:nn` instead:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \frac:n#1{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{(\d+)\/(\d+)}{\c{tfrac}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cB\{\2\cE\}}\l_tmpa_tl 
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl 
}
\cs_set_eq:NN \mfrac \frac:n 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{tikzpicture}[line~join=round,scale=3.5]
\draw[->, thin] (-0.1,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=west, inner~sep=2pt] {$x$};
\clist_map_inline:nn{1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,12/9}
{
  \draw (#1,-.01) -- (#1,.01);
  \node[below,scale=0.5] at (#1,0) {$\mfrac{#1}$};
}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

sorry i complicate the matter

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
\draw[->, thin] (-0.1,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
\foreach \x/\y in {1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,12/9}
{
  \draw[red] (\x/\y,-.01) -- +(0,.02);
  \node[cyan,scale=0.5,below] at (\x/\y,0){$\tfrac{\x}{\y}$}; 
}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another solution, but less perfect：

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mfrac#1/#2{$\tfrac{#1}{#2}$} % \mfrac#1/#2 --> \tfrac{#1}{#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
\draw[->, thin] (-0.1,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,12/9,18/12}
{
  \draw (\x,-.01) -- (\x,.01);
  \node[below,scale=0.5] at (\x,0) {\expandafter\mfrac\x};
}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I think it's more perfect：

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%define the command \mfrac =========== \mfrac{#1/#2} --> \tfrac{#1}{#2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \frac:n#1{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{(\d+)\/(\d+)}{$\c{tfrac}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cB\{\2\cE\}$}\l_tmpa_tl 
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl 
}
\cs_set_eq:NN \mfrac \frac:n 
\ExplSyntaxOff  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=3.5]
\draw[->, thin] (-0.1,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=west, inner sep=2pt] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,12/9,18/12}
{
  \draw (\x,-.01) -- (\x,.01);
  \node[below,scale=0.5] at (\x,0) {\expandafter\mfrac\expandafter{\x}};
}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find the exp3 syntax even more impenetrable than the TikZ syntax, so I really want to use TiKZ's `\foreach` with pairs.

Comment: Aha! So the / in each member of the list already forms the pair.

Comment: I added another solution！

Answer (score 4):

Some words of explanation. Hopefully this will address your misconceptions, if any.

- The cleanest solution is included in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648071/250119), just write `\x/\y`.

```
\foreach \x/\y in {1/9,2/9,3/9,4/9,5/9,6/9,12/9}
{
  \draw[red] (\x/\y,-.01) -- +(0,.02);
  \node[cyan,scale=0.5,below] at (\x/\y,0){$\tfrac{\x}{\y}$}; 
}
```

- Here note that the syntax, of both the code above and the previous answer, is to pass (something that fully expands to) **literally `1/9`** into TikZ. This code will work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (1/9, 0) {abc};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- In the code of the [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648003/250119)...

```
    \foreach \i in {1/9,2/8,1/3,2/3,7/9,8/9} {
        \show \i
        \draw (\i,-.01)--(\i,.01);
            \node[anchor=west, rotate=-75, font=\tiny] at (\i,0) {$\small{\i}$};
    }
```

The value of `\i` is assigned literally the string `1/9`, instead of the value e.g. `0.111` or some magic. I add `\show \i` in to demo that, you'll see on the terminal

```
> \i=macro:
->1/9.
```

- Using `\numexpr` like the code below...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (\the\numexpr 1/9\relax, 0) {abc};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will not work as you intend. Read `texdoc etex_man`, you'll see division "rounds to the nearest integer", so it becomes 0.

Comment: If something doesn't make sense to you ask you wish to learn TeX programming seriously, start with reading the TeXbook.

Comment: No, it's not TeX syntax in general that is at issue here. It is the very specialized and (to me) peculiar syntax of TikZ.

Comment: Yes, I quite agree with what you deem "the cleanest solution." The TikZ documentation on `\foreach` just did not make clear to me, although probably it should have, that `1/9`, e.g., would suffice to create the pair.

Comment: @murray Ah I see. This syntax is documented in a different part, "Multiple variables" in page 1003 (hence the confusion, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2.5mm]{standalone}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=4.5]
    \draw (0,.01)--(0,-.01)  node[below] {\tiny 0};
    \draw[thick,black,-latex]   (-.1,0) -- (1.1,0) node[right] {$x$};
    
    \foreach \i/\n in {{1/9}/$\frac19$,{2/9}/$\frac29$,{1/3}/$\frac13$,{2/3}/$\frac23$,{7/9}/$\frac79$,{8/9}/$\frac89$}{%
    \draw (\i,.01)--(\i,-.01) node[below] {\tiny \n};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

COMMENT: think at this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            $x^2/9$ & $ x^{2/9}$ & $x^a/b$ & $x^{a/b}$ \\
            $\frac{1}{9}$ & $\frac29$ & $\frac{a}{b}$ & $\frac ab$  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

and at his results:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly not what the OP wants to do, it computes the coordinate manually.

Comment: I have edited the my code.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro: That `\foreach` syntax is what I was trying to get at. But what you show is even more mysterious than my reading of pgfmanual indicates: while the first component, like `{1/9}`, of a item in the iteration list uses braces to enclose it, the second component, following the `/`, like `$\frac19$` does not not!

Comment: Expressions such as `\frac19` are very un-*La*TeX-ish!

Comment: @murray Read guru manuals and enjoy my results!